# UIPageViewController with one constant background image

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I want a PageViewController that just has one constant background. Kind of similar to the tutorial in Evernote's iOS app.

I was thinking about making the UIPageViewController's background transparent and each view in the page controller transparent as well but I don't think its working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have code to share?

Comment: Let me just throw up a quick repo. I'll have it up by tonight. Thanks @Sean

Comment: Here you go @Sean https://github.com/AndrewSB/PageViewDemo

Comment: So instead of the image scrolling by each time I just want the text to move and the image to stay still

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made some edits and added some notes to your project which can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5296996/PageViewDemo-master.zip)

Just reiterating those notes:

- Create imageView with screen view bounds
- Set contentMode to `.ScaleAspectFit` to avoid image distortion.
- Similarly, you can use `.ScaleAspectFill` if your image's aspect ratio differs from the view's aspect ratio
- Add the imageView as a subview and send it to the back so that it doesn't cover your Tutorial views
- In `Main.storyboard`, i've removed the tutorialViewController's view background image and set the background color to `.clearColor()`

Comment: thank you, that is so awesome. I didn't realize you could add a subview to the pageVC

Answer (score 10):

On your `UIPageViewController` add the `UIImageView` definition on top (Swift):

```
var imageView: UIImageView?
```

And then in `viewDidLoad:` add:

```
imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background")!)
imageView!.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
view.insertSubview(imageView!, atIndex: 0)
```